# Input field which is not visible to user

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to load my ASP.NET page, receive user input and base on that do  some action. Problem is I don't want to let the user see what is he/she typing and the input itself should not be visible as well. Also I want to process postback if the length of an input is of length 6.

Closest I can get to this is a textbox with backgroud-color:transparent and no border. Also autopostback is enabled. Textbox gets focus, when user presses enter, postback is called, text lenght is checked and then I do some stuff in code behind. Unfortunately user can see text as he/she types and enter has to be pressed.

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

//For all of you who wonder why do I want to do this:

*Page is loaded, user sees empty page. She/he put his RFID card on RFID reader. The reader sends input + enter (should be easy to setup on reader itself) to the page. Postback appears, length is checked, some information are written on page. I do not want user to see anything (text from textbox especially) before postback.*
Now I don't have the reader and the way how to hide input but I need to test it. If I could figure out how to do postback without sending enter it would be even better.

Comment: Use an `<input type="hidden"/>` and alter the value with JavaScript ?

Comment: Can you use a password style text-box?

Comment: I get you don't want users to see "what" they are typing. Can I ask, why on earth do you not want a user to see "that" they are typing?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET there is a 'visible' property, but that may disable the input. Maybe you could give that a try.

You could also set the text color to the same as the background color (transparent) - also worth a try.

I would set the HTML5 password attribute on the input field. The user could then see the input, but not the characters they typed.

Comment: `visible` is a server-side property, the item won't render on the page if you use `visible="false"` with a `runat="server"` tag.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not completely clear on what exactly you want, but to the best of my understanding, here's a solution:

Create a textbox that is invisible using CSS. On your submit button, add a JS/jQuery function that checks if the input is six characters long, and performs the postback only if that is the case - anything else and the function will return `false`, and the page will not post-back.

Is this what you had in mind?

---

**ASP.Net**

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" cssclass="invis"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" onClientClick="return checkSixChars();"></asp:Button>
```

**CSS**

```
.invis {
  border: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function checkSixChars() {
    var $input = $(".invis").first();
    if ($input.val().length == 6) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: is this not what the OP has already? Also, type "Hello" then Ctrl-A and you can see what you typed.

Comment: If the user wants to see what they typed, that can just go to "Inspect Element" and there's the entire page, hidden fields and all. I'd assumed nobody in their right mind would think hiding a textbox or using hiddenfields would serve a *security* purpose, just a stylistic one.

Answer (score 0):

try do the following:

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function(){
        $("#teste").keypress(function(event){
          //console.clear();
          //console.log(event);      
          $(this).val("");
          $("#testeHidden").val($("#testeHidden").val() + event.key);
          var value = $("#testeHidden").val();
          if(value.length < 6)
            return false;
          $("#secretButton").click();          
          return false;      
        });
        $("#viewer").click(function(){
          alert($("#testeHidden").val());
        });
        $("#secretButton").click(function(){
          console.log("I will post to the server the following value:");
          console.log($("#testeHidden").val());
          $("#testeHidden").val("");
        });
      });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="teste" />
    <input type="hidden" id="testeHidden" />
    <input type="button" value="show" id="viewer" />
    <input type="button" value="show" style="display:none" id="secretButton" />
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: This looks solid. I'll give it a try. Thank you.